# Django: Why does NullBooleanField accept non-boolean answers?

Tags: python, django

Say I have a NullBooleanField on the Zoo model:

```
class Zoo(models.model):
    lion = NullBooleanField()
```

Why does it let me save a non-boolean field which then defaults to true, rather than erroring out? For instance:

```
my_zoo = Zoo.objects.create()
my_zoo.lion = "Simba"
my_zoo.save() # Surprisingly, no error here.
>>>my_zoo.lion # True
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `NullBooleanField` is just trying to convert to a Python object, in this case either `None`, `True`, or `False`.

Thus, anything `bool` casting will work on, will work on this field, since that's what it does in the background.

---

#### Edit:

This may be a bug. Looking at the [source code for this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2039), you can see it is only supposed to accept the values `True`, `False`, `None`, `'t'`, `'f'`, `'True'`, `'False'`, `'None'`, `'0'`, and `'1'` (not even `0` and `1`!). This has been the case at least since Django 1.5. What version of Django are you using?

---

#### Edit 2:

I tried to reproduce this using Django 1.7 and had even weirder results.

```
>>> zoo = Zoo.objects.create()
>>> zoo.lion = 'Simba'
>>> zoo.save()
>>> zoo.lion
'Simba'
>>> type(zoo.lion)
<type 'str'>
```

Of course, I have just overwritten the attribute on the local object here. I can also do this:

```
>>> zoo.walrus = 'Simba'
>>> zoo.walrus
'Simba'
```

However, when I refresh the local object by pulling it back out of the database:

```
>>> zoo = Zoo.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> zoo.lion
True
>>> type(zoo.lion)
<type 'bool'>
```

At no point was an exception raised, but it did get converted to a boolean. I'm beginning to second-guess where `to_python` even gets called.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.7.4. And yes - it seemed weird to me too! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Honestly I thought I knew what was going on at first but the more I look the less I am sure. I know that forms raise `ValidationError` for this but that breaks `model.save` and the admin, so there's at least 3 ways Django tries to handle this. There's also nothing in their unit tests for NullBooleanField except trying it with basic `True`, `False`, and `None`! I would say raise an issue on their GitHub and see what the official word is.

Comment: [`get_prep_value`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2066) is what converts any truthy value to `True` when saving the model. This does not affect the value present on the model itself, but it affects what is saved to the database. That's why it is `True` when you reload the model.